# Unable to capture the array data from multi dimension array

Tags: angular, typescript, multidimensional-array, rxjs, jsonresponse

In Angular, I am getting multi dimension array as a response from backend. I want to capture only one array data into my new array with only few values from it (id and fname). I tried multiple ways but things did not work for me. Below are the details.

**Multi dimension array json response from backend.**

```
{
   "data":[
      {
         "SRno":{
            "label":"newtest",
            "label1":"10 VINS"
         },
         "attachment":{
            "value":null,
            "label":null
         },
         "username":{
            "id":2,
            "fname":"test1",
            "lname":"test11"
         }        
      },
      {
         "SRno":{
            "label":"newtest1",
            "label":"10 VINS"
         },
          "attachment":{
            "value":null,
            "label":null
         },
         "username":{
            "id":3,
            "name":"test2",
            "lname":"test22"
           }
      },
      {
         "SRno":{
            "label":"newtest2",
            "label":"10 VINS"
         },
          "attachment":{
            "value":null,
            "label":null
         },
         "username":{
            "id":4,
            "name":"test3",
            "lname":"test33"
         }
      },
      {
         "SRno":{
            "label":"newtest3",
            "label":"10 VINS"
         },
          "attachment":{
            "value":null,,
            "label":null
         },
         "username":{
            "id":5,
            "name":"test4",
            "lname":"test44"
         }
      }      
   ],
   "result":null
}
```

**Expected Output:**

```
"Newarray":[
         {
            "id":2,
            "fname":"test1"
         },
         {    
            "id":3,
            "name":"test2"
         },
         {
            "id":4,
            "name":"test3"
         },
         {
            "id":5,
            "name":"test4"
         }
        ]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
response['data'].map(({ username: { id, fname }}) => ({ id, fname }));
```

If you want to take `name` instead of `fname` when `fname` is missing, you can do this:

```
response['data'].map(({ username: { id, fname, name }}) => ({ id, fname: fname ?? name }));
```

[Take a look at this playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBATgUwgB3BBMC8MDeAoGQgIgBMBDKMogLgG0DDH9GXiBlAJTBBudf6IAbMgCMEgmkTAIA7lCRQiAGgb8WQ0eICMkrQAYYANQCSAOTZFV-AL4q1xCpWAALALYIwi6n3vEAbmSCAK4INGBBgoJ2vsTCYhLU4ZFWrLYp6kHocGBk7rzpAgCWJDQATNExRABmOXnURPLQOhW+QrWh9Y1QWjoFhNb26Wn8PgKc3PkxsZoJUrJdzX3qceK6Bibmlr7DrY5kLu6ek1NEAcEdSVFLjBrxYRGCSztqRJkI2bkdo-ZExTQAzC0fu1JF1SsprrEQZ0FKVwZDrEMgbglkRxjxvJCYLdVvVpHJYRCptiVrN9EYzBYnsj1HsDh4vN8XmcQvdIjTWDiEpdqai3h86kyiiVqAAWDnqaENBT-IknQRSrr-WVPJHpIXsLgYjXLGaSfFKuWVUlrCmbXmVOluBnHSosi4PCU3E2JB4Wn786E6m5-agAVidxEVClFRtaCs+oJDodVNn4qgAuhUiIgIBEvDzEXhQJAQIIEAA6QQgADmAApU6hIAhaAByciUWsJguuMjIMtlnAwT2fai4YpKGqfJTtAbWACUWAAfDBOzABzAh+4+0uMAB+NcwdowCfjgDceCAA).

Answer (score 0):

Using your data as an example, and assigning the variable from the backend to `payload` you could do it this way

```
const usernameObj = payload.data.map(obj => ({ id: obj.username.id, fname: obj.username.fname ?? obj.username.name }))
```